# What is Arthur referring to when he says "This is where it capsized"?

Tags: bone-tomahawk

In the movie *Bone Tomahawk*, Arthur has managed to get near the hillside cave of the "troglodytes" and says to himself something like, "This is where it capsized."

He may have been in a dry river bed, and maybe he sees the wreck of a boat, but his is not clear to me at all. So what does he mean? What is he referring to?

I found some discussion of this term on Reddit from 7 years ago and people seem to think this is a figure of speech, meaning essentially that this is where things went badly. I've never heard or read anyone use "capsized" in this way but it sounds plausible since apparently I am not the only one not to see a boat or river in that scene.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about it meaning, "This is where it all went bad".  It's not a common phrase, but in context it's clearly meant to convey the same thing as "This is a bad idea", but in a more colorful way.

Comment: Whose "bad idea?" Bad idea is different that a bad event.

Comment: To approach the Troglodyte cave

Comment: Yeah, this is where the sh*t hit the fan, went south, went pear-shaped, come a cropper, go awry, go Pete Tong, tits up, sideways, wheels came off, etc